# Need regex to remove spaces between multiple new lines characters

Tags: java, android, html, string

I am working on some rawString in which i need to remove \n from some places and Some where i need to go in next line if there showing \n.For Example Input:-

```
 ** As the coronavirus impact weighs, LMT to advance more\nthan $50 mln to small, medium-sized business partners in its\nsupply chain to protect jobs, support economy \n  \n  *New line should start\n\nregular \n  \n \n  \n text.
```

I am getting the result Partially using this code

```
 String str = input.replaceAll("\\n","~").replaceAll("~\\s+",System.lineSeparator()+System.lineSeparator()).replaceAll("~", " ");
```

Result right now i am getting:

```
** As the coronavirus impact weighs, LMT to advance more than $50 mln to small, medium-sized business partners in its supply chain to protect jobs, support economy


*New line should startregular 





text.
```

but problem is where i am getting more than one time "\n" consecutively  , that all \n replace into one "\n", because at this time where i am getting "\n" with space its going to next line, e,g so it like "\n  \n Keyword" in this case  "Keyword" is showing in next line that correct but creating one extra line above that a problem. Can anyone please help on this.

Expected:-

```
** As the coronavirus impact weighs, LMT to advance more than $50 mln to small, medium-sized business partners in its supply chain to protect jobs, support economy

*New line should startregular 

text.
```

**Input Pattern for New line**

`\n  \n    \n  SomeText`, `\n\n  SomeText\n`,`\n \n\n  SomeText`

In all above Pattern `someText` will start in next line.

**Pattern will create space only**

`\nSomeText`, `\n\n\nSomeText\n\n`, `\nSomeText`

in these all cases will create only space `" "`,

Comment: according to this edit you want to remove all spaces between the` \ns` and just want to keep `\ns` right?

Comment: yes exactly remove space bettween all `\ns`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following update:

```
String str = input
    .replaceAll("(\\n\\s+){2,}","~") // find duplicate linefeeds with optional spaces
    .replaceAll("\\n"," ") // replace remaining linefeeds with spaces
    .replaceAll("\\s{3,}", "") // remove redundant spaces
    .replaceAll("\\s{2}", " ") // replace duplicate spaces with one
    .replaceAll("~", System.lineSeparator() + System.lineSeparator() // restore linefeeds
);
```

It produces the following text:

```
** As the coronavirus impact weighs, LMT to advance more than $50 mln to small, medium-sized business partners in its supply chain to protect jobs, support economy 

*New line should start regular 

text.
```

**Update for new test cases**

```
String str = input
        .replaceAll("(\\n +\\n| \\n+ )","~") // mark duplicate linefeeds with optional spaces
        .replaceAll("\\n+"," ") // replace remaining linefeeds with spaces
        .replaceAll("(~\\s*)+","~") // remove duplicate linefeed marks with optional spaces
        .replaceAll("\\s{3,}", "") // remove redundant spaces
        .replaceAll("\\s{2}", " ") // replace duplicate spaces
        .replaceAll("~", System.lineSeparator() + System.lineSeparator()) // restore linefeeds
    ;
    System.out.println("[" + str + "]");
```

*Case 2*: "\n  \n    \n  SomeText1, \n\n  SomeText2\n,\n \n\n  SomeText3"

```
[\n
\n
SomeText1,\n
\n
SomeText2 ,\n
\n
SomeText3]
```

*Case 3*: "\nSomeText1, \n\n\nSomeText2\n\n, \nSomeText3"

```
[ SomeText1, SomeText2 , SomeText3]
```

Comment: only one i am seeing i am going to next line only where i am getting "space+ \n +space" or "\n+\n+space" else i showing single space. is it possible if i want to go next line where i am getting \n+space or if  "\n+space" more than one time, it will replace into one and go to next line.

Comment: where i am getting this "\n        \n    \n    But " creating a one extra line

Comment: Sorry, it seems I cannot quite understand you.  Do you want to have special handling when there are three  and more `\n` characters?  Please update your test and expected results.

Comment: Updates please check if you understand

Comment: @Navjot.jassal Please check the updated solution.  All tests passing.  I will appreciate your acceptance of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If i didn't get it wrong you want to convert the multiple `\n` and spaces in one `\n` then

please try `s = s.replaceAll("\\n\\s+\\b","\n");`

**for this particular use case output was**

```
As the coronavirus impact weighs, LMT to advance more
than $50 mln to small, medium-sized business partners in its
supply chain to protect jobs, support economy 
New line should start
regular 
text.
```

**In general**

It will convert `\n\n   \n \n` , `\n \n   \n` , `\n  \n\n   \n   \n` these kinds of patterns into a single new line ie. `\n`

Comment: No like that, I want to go next line only when i get \n+space  other wise \n is replacing with " ", if i am getting \n+space  \n+space  on that case i want to remove one \n+space

Comment: i didn't quite understand that , the above regular expression will work also for multiple `\n` even if there are no spaces, if that is not what you want, please provide example patterns and their expected replacement , similarly as i provided in my answer

Comment: Updated please check make Sense

Comment: This replacement won't pass any of the tests :)

Comment: @AlexRudenko you're right , i tested it incorrectly , i was actually confuse about his requirment, the one in the answer solves what he asks in the question title , but now he say he wants keep the `\ns`